# ConcurrentHashMap usage

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

Another question today.

I am trying to understand if I should use a ConcurrentHashMap for one of my service or not.

I have a service `DataService` that fetches data every 10sec from a database and puts it in a map `dataMap = Map<Key,Data>` 
This service is scheduled on a different thread than my main thread.

In my main thread, every now and then i have to get an element from the map `dataMap`
The main thread only use `get` and never updates the map.

My question, does the `dataMap` have to be a ConcurrentHashMap in this case?

Thanks

Comment: If your map needs to be ***modified*** by several threads concurrently, Then go for `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: Can't be answered without the following being mentioned.
1. Can your service be called multiple times asynchronously?
2. At what level is the map declared and at what level is it being modified (instance / class/ method-local?
3. Do you always need updated data to be returned from the map?

Comment: It _sounds_ like you should be using Caffeine.

Comment: @TheLostMind, when my process starts up its creates an empty map then queries the database for the data at which point the size of the map and keys never change. Every 10 secs it queries the data and updates the values for each key.

Comment: Note that by update i mean i do this `Data data = map.get(key); data.setValue1(value1); data.setValue2(value2)`.

Comment: @Himura - I see. In that case, You should be using ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: Please update with a piece of code that you have and want to be evaluated. It will be easier and clearer as to what is being talked about

Answer (score 1):

You have to address the reader and writer accessing the map concurrently. Specifically, a HashMap is not sufficient. From the JavaDoc:

"Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more mappings."

Adding a new map entry from the database is a structural modification and may result in a ConcurrentModificationException.

Note that ConcurrentHashMap is still very efficient. From the Javadoc:

"A hash table supporting full concurrency of retrievals and high expected concurrency for updates. .... Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block, so may overlap with update operations (including put and remove)."

Comment: Note that I only add entries at the start of the process. Every 10sec, i only update the entries. Meaning i do this `Data data = map.get(key); data.setValue1(value1); data.setValue2(value2)` I dont "add" new entries anymore

Comment: OK, then a hashmap is sufficient since that is no structural modification.

Comment: Using a HashMap might lead to dirty reads, since it isn't synchronized.

Comment: Correct, but a ConcurrentHashMap won't solve this problem either. To avoid dirty reads (value1 is new but value2 is old), you could make a copy of the object, change the copy and then replace the old copy in the map.